# Unable to increase size of tkinter frame canvas.create_window, Hides CSV columns

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have employee CSV file having below columns
name,age,education,mailid,mobilenumber,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4
using Canvas Frame, create_window(4,4) here is my below code
I tried with increasing width and height

but upto address2 column only visible, last two cloumns Address3,Address4 not visible in the screen
Anyone have any idea ? please suggest

employee.csv

```
name,age,education,mailid,mobilenumber,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4
abc,23,bsc,abc@gmail.com,9999999999,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abcdf,26,bsc,abcdf@gmail.com,88888888888,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abc,23,bsc,abc@gmail.com,9999999999,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abcdf,26,bsc,abcdf@gmail.com,88888888888,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abc,23,bsc,abc@gmail.com,9999999999,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abcdf,26,bsc,abcdf@gmail.com,88888888888,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abc,23,bsc,abc@gmail.com,9999999999,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abcdf,26,bsc,abcdf@gmail.com,88888888888,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abc,23,bsc,abc@gmail.com,9999999999,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4
abcdf,26,bsc,abcdf@gmail.com,88888888888,addr1,addr2,addr3,addr4




import csv
import os
import codecs
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        UI_Widgets(self)
def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=450,height=300)   
root=Tk()
SIZEX = 800
SIZEY = 600
POSX  = 100
POSY  = 100
root.title("MY APPLICATION")
root.configure(background="#e7e6e6")
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (SIZEX, SIZEY, POSX, POSY))
myframe=Frame(root,relief=GROOVE,width=450,height=400,bd=2,background="white",bg="black")
myframe.place(x=50,y=100)
canvas=Canvas(myframe)
scrollable_frame=Frame(canvas,bg ="#f4f6f9")
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set,bg='#f4f6f9')
myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((4,4),window=scrollable_frame,anchor='nw' )
scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
sep = ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame,orient=VERTICAL)
def UI_Widgets(self):
    self.Button_readcsv= Button(root,text ="Browse CSV FILE", command = readcsv)
    self.Button_readcsv.place(x=40, y=40)
            
def readcsv():
    filepath=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Open file",filetypes=(("CSV Files","*.csv"),))   
    try:
            with codecs .open(filepath, encoding="utf8") as my_file:
                reader = csv.DictReader(my_file, delimiter=',')
                headers = reader.fieldnames              
                i=0
                horline=0
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[0] ,bg ="#f4f6f9" ).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=2, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[1],bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=4, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[2],bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=0,column=5,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=6, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[3],bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=0,column=7,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=8, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')    
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[4],bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=0,column=9,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=10, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')   
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[5],bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=0,column=11,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=12, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')    
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[6],bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=0,column=13,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=14, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')    
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[7],bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=0,column=15,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=16, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')  
                tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=headers[8],bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=0,column=17,sticky='n')
                tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=18, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns') 
                for row in reader:        
                    if(i==0):
                        i=3
                    else:
                        i=i+2                           
                    if(horline==0):
                        horline=2
                    else:
                        horline=horline+2  
                        name = row[headers[0]]
                        age = row[headers[1]]
                        education = row[headers[2]]
                        mailid = row[headers[3]]   
                        mobilenumber = row[headers[4]]
                        Address1 = row[headers[5]]
                        Address2 = row[headers[6]]
                        Address3 = row[headers[7]]   
                        Address4 = row[headers[8]]   
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame,text=name,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=1,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=2, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')                                         
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=age,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=3,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=4, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')                                    
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=education,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=5,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=6, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')                                  
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=mailid,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=7,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=8, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')      
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=mobilenumber,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=9,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=10, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')  
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=Address1,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=11,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=12, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')   
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=Address2,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=13,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=14, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')                           
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=Address3,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=15,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=16, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')   
                        tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=Address4,bg ="#f4f6f9").grid(row=i,column=17,sticky='n')
                        tkinter.ttk.Separator(scrollable_frame, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=18, row=0, rowspan=i+1, sticky='ns')  
    except(IOError):
           print("Error Reading in CSV File ")          
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp = MyApp()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably changing with the width and height didn't worked because you are changing the frame size and the frame will adjust for the size of the canvas inside it, unless you prevent it using `pack_propagate(False)`. But it will not help you because you have to edit the canvas width in the `my_function()` method:

```
def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=450,height=300)
```

But to be sure it will always fit in your canvas it would be better to add an horizontal scroll bar:

```
myscrollbarx=Scrollbar(myframe,orient="horizontal",command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=myscrollbarx.set,bg='#f4f6f9')
myscrollbarx.pack(side="bottom",fill="x")
```

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow